# SQL Count per hour for all DTM values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an existing range of values which have an Oracle DTM format such as *22-NOV-18 12.20.45.430838000*

My aim was to do a count per hour across the whole range of values. I want a count for all of the unique values across the different days.

This proved difficult as the extract function is only able to extract 1 date type from the field, where i need the multiple values.

I was able to write the following query which gives me the count per day across the whole range.

```
select trunc(created_dtm), count(*) CreatedCount from

(select ord.order_id, ordser.service_id, ord.product_type, ord.created_dtm ,ord.last_modified_dtm from SCADRON_OWNER.orders ord, SCADRON_OWNER.order_subtype os, SCADRON_OWNER.order_services ordser where ord.order_id = os.order_id and ordser.order_id = ord.order_id and os.subtype = 'FttcActiveLineTakeoverUpgrade' and ord.order_status
= 'Completed' )

group by trunc(created_dtm) order by trunc(created_dtm);
```

producing results as such:

[image]

I however would like to refine this so that I can have a count for all the values per hour, is there an easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select cast(trunc(created_dtm, 'hh') as timestamp),
       count(*)
from SCADRON_OWNER.orders ord join
     SCADRON_OWNER.order_subtype os
     on ord.order_id = os.order_id join
     SCADRON_OWNER.order_services ordser 
     on ordser.order_id = ord.order_id 
where os.subtype = 'FttcActiveLineTakeoverUpgrade' and 
      ord.order_status = 'Completed' 
group by cast(trunc(created_dtm, 'hh') as timestamp)
order by min(created_dtm);
```

This converts the value to a timestamp so you can see it.  Alternatively, convert to a string:

```
select to_char(created_dtm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') || ':00:00',
       count(*)
from SCADRON_OWNER.orders ord join
     SCADRON_OWNER.order_subtype os
     on ord.order_id = os.order_id join
     SCADRON_OWNER.order_services ordser 
     on ordser.order_id = ord.order_id 
where os.subtype = 'FttcActiveLineTakeoverUpgrade' and 
      ord.order_status = 'Completed' 
group by to_char(created_dtm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
order by min(created_dtm);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly @GordonLinoff . The 2nd query worked whereas the 1st gave an error of "ORA-00979: not a group by expression".